# How to match flatpak themes with GNOME dark theme?

Tags: gnome, themes, flatpak

I'm a beginner with Linux and I think I messed up the command lines when I tried to match flatpak apps with ubuntu's dark theme because not only it didn't work but now flatpak apps look ugly (a bit as if they came from 2010).

I tried to reset flatpak permissions and to delete/reinstall flatpak packages but it doesn't seem to work.

I would like flatpak apps to use the Yaru theme again.

About this picture: on the left is Bottles, a flatpak app with a weird theme, and on the right is a snap app with a normal ubuntu theme.

[image: screenshot]

PS : I am on Ubuntu 22.04 using X11

Comment: I think the weird looking "ugly" theme that "looks as if it came from 2010" is the Gnome Desktop Environment's factory default theme, that's called Adwaita Theme.

Comment: @Louise Also, this is more like from 1998 rather than 2010. In 2010, we had fancy glass like theme of Windows 7 :)

Comment: You can install the flatpak app flatseal, and use it to change individual app themes.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. You'll be able to accept your answer after a short time, that's enough to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anybody having the same issue just install [sylepak](https://github.com/refi64/stylepak) it'll install the theme you currently use to flatpak apps.